# What should be proper p value cutoff point for multiple comparison case?

Tags: p-value, multiple-comparisons, kruskal-wallis-test, adjustment

I have 4 conditions, (Control, Stim-1, Stim-2, Stim-3) and 9 different proteins expression levels in each conditions.  The sample number of each protein expression level in each conditions are about 40 ~ 130 individuals.

I would like to set significant level as 0.05. 
In order to control for the overall significance level of 0.05 considering nine simultaneous tests(9 protein expression tests), the significant level is modified 0.05/9 = 0.00555556

Then, there is pair-wise comparisons adjustment. 
So I divide 0.0055556 with 6 pairs numbers (con-stim1, con-stim2, con-stim3, stim1-stim2, stim1-stim3, stim2-stim3)
0.05/9/ ((4*3)/2)  = 0.000925925

Is it right ?
Any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, the method is correct in the sense that you are performing a conventional Bonferroni correction for multiple testing, with the result that the family-wise error rate, i.e. the expected number of false positives, is controlled at 0.05. However, this often has very low power. 

May I suggest you consider controlling the false discovery rate? It is easy to interpret and powerful. There is tons of free-to-use software available for FDR control.
Intro: https://brainder.org/2011/09/05/fdr-corrected-fdr-adjusted-p-values/

Comment: Thanks. I was curious about that p-value cut off point. Actually, I have used PMCMR R package which has "posthoc.kruskal.dunn.test()" function. My data was not met the assumption of ANOVA. I had to choose nonparametric kruskal-wallis test. I chose Dunn test for KW posthoc method.  "posthoc.kruskal.dunn.test()" output p-values could be adjusted with Bejamini and Hochberg FDR method. Therefore, the p.adjusted values (actually, q-val of FDR) were increased than unadjusted p-values.

Comment: So, now I have an idea with your comment, I can use 0.0055556 for  a "FDR adjusted posthoc kruskal wallis Dunn test p-values".   Thank you Eric.